# Missing icon on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, icons

I have a relatively clean install of 16.04 running, nothing fiddled about with too much. I use pCloud for my online storage which comes with a really good app to do syncs and what-not. I turned it on this morning and the icon on the tray has vanished! Dropbox is still there, as is Mega... but no Pcloud! The program appears to be running, but without the icon I can't control it.

Has anyone come across this? I know the Dropbox icon missing is quite a common thing, could it be the same kind of thing?